# Lock screen is blinking on wake up, revealing desktop

Tags: 20.04, unity, lock-screen

I upgraded my Dell Vostro laptop from Ubuntu 16 to 20.04. I continue using Unity, however I checked out Gnome after the upgrade.

Now every time I open up my laptop, the lock screen blinks one or two times. Sometimes the screen goes blank for a moment but sometimes I see my desktop for a second or two before the lock screen comes back.

This is not only inconvenient but also a security flaw because anyone who opens up my laptop has a chance to see what I was working on. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What display manager are you using?

Comment: @AlexFullam I am using gdm3.

Comment: Did you try reconfiguring gdm3? If that doesn't work, try reinstalling it. You can reconfigure it with "sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3" and you can reinstall it with "sudo apt --reinstall install gdm3." Let me know if you've already tried this. :)